# Angularjs ng-init with ng-selected issue

Tags: angularjs

In the following code if ng-selected value does not become True then why does ng-init not select the `option value=3` . If ng-selected becomes true it should show the value selected else the default value i.e, option 3

Right drop down shows no option selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="issue" id="issue" ng-model="item.issue" ng-init="item.issue='3'">
     <option value="3" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '3'">Task</option>
     <option value="4" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '4'">Task4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ng-init` you are setting `issue` to `'3'`, not `item.issue.id`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="issue" id="issue" ng-model="item.issue" ng-init="item.issue.id='3'">
     <option value="3" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '3'">Task</option>
     <option value="4" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '4'">Task4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: some how its still not showing up the value even if i set it to ng-init="item.issue.id='3'"

Comment: What are you setting `item.issue` to in your controller?  You may need, `item.issue = { id: '3' }`.  OR something like `item = { issue: { id: '3' }}`

Answer (score 0):

I think ng-init should set value of id

```
<select class="form-control" name="issue" id="issue" ng-model="item.issue" ng-init="item.issue.id='3'">
     <option value="3" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '3'">Task</option>
     <option value="4" ng-selected="item.issue['id'] == '4'">Task4</option>
</select>
```